# Hyperledger Fabric cross communication between 2 or more networks

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

Is it possible to have one peer be part of two different Hyperledger fabric networks (where each network has its own Orderers and Fabric CA)?

I'm trying to achieve a cross-communication between 2 Hyperledger fabric networks.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Fabric Peers can be joined to different networks (Orderer clusters).
The only pre-requisite would be that the org, the peer belongs to, has been joined to the channel.

That peer would then be able to act as an endorsing peer for both networks and would also get all the transactions replicated.

Per default, the peer would not be able to forward transactions from the one network to the other network and act as some kind of a bridge.